# Collections sort - bug in large list

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, collections

i'm trying to sort a list of object by page number (if the page is equal so by location) like this:

```
Collections.sort(arlToTort, new Comparator<UserDefinedLink>() {
@Override
public int compare(UserDefinedLink lhs, UserDefinedLink rhs) {
    if(lhs.getPageNum() > rhs.getPageNum()){
        return 0;
    }else {
        if(lhs.getPageNum() == rhs.getPageNum()){
            double rhsY =  getLinkYLocation(rhs.getLocationStart());
            double lhsY =  getLinkYLocation(lhs.getLocationStart());
            if(rhsY > lhsY){
                return 0;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
  }
});
```

when i set a small list (less then 32 items) it works fine but when the list is up to 32 items the sort is not work fine, here is example of log after sort:

**list with 31 items:**

```
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 2 
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 4
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 4
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 14
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 14
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 20
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 25
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 26
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 26
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 28
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 28
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 30
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 31
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 34
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 35
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 39
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 42
 D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 44
```

**list with 32 items:**

```
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: num of items : 32
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 4
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 4
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 26
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 26
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 28
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 28
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 30
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 34
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 39
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 44
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 2
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 9
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 10
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 14
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 14
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 20
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 25
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 31
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 35
D/getSortedListByPageNumber: Page: 42
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are missing some constraint as `compareTo` returns

```
Returns a negative integer => object is less than
Returns a zero => object are equals
Returns a positive integer => object is greater than
```

so when object is `greater` then it should return positive value rather than `0` which is used in case of `equality`

so  use

```
Collections.sort(arlToTort, new Comparator<UserDefinedLink>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UserDefinedLink lhs, UserDefinedLink rhs) {
            if(lhs.getPageNum() > rhs.getPageNum()){
                return 1;
               //      ^ greater 
            }else {
                // for equality 
                if(lhs.getPageNum() == rhs.getPageNum()){
                    double rhsY =  getLinkYLocation(rhs.getLocationStart());
                    double lhsY =  getLinkYLocation(lhs.getLocationStart());
                    if(rhsY > lhsY){
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if(rhsY == lhsY){ return 0;}
                    else{
                        return -1;
                    }
                }else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @gilcohen i am glad that i could help , happy coding